# Upgraded from 16.04 to 17.04 with no issues until restart, after which Ubuntu fails to boot

Tags: boot, upgrade, 17.04, tmp

[image: screnshot-of-error-message]

Issue pictured above. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> isn't really helpful. Booting up to this point takes 15 minutes.  The PC is a Dell. Ubuntu has been working smoothly until now. Ive read other articles on "the tpm cant reach region for resource" error, but they were incomprehensible and unhelpful.

The install went smoothly, nothing was interrupted. After the computer asked to restart, this occurred. I've backed everything up, but I'm looking for a solution that is more convenient than reinstalling the OS.

```
kernel is 4.10.0-42-generic
```

Edit: Managed to login after 20 minutes. But the computer is remarkably slow, takes several seconds to open terminal, etc. Additionally, my touchscreen and keyboard functionality is gone. Using a virtual keyboard right now because mouse is still available.

```
description: Portable Computer
    product: Inspiron 5555 (Inspiron 5555)
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    version: A08
    serial: *******
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=portable sku=Inspiron 5555 uuid=44454C4C-3100-1032-8048-C2C04F4D3732

  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A08
       date: 08/27/2015
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 8128KiB
       capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb zipboot smartbattery biosbootspecification uefi

  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 12
       slot: L1 CACHE
       size: 320KiB
       capacity: 320KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1

  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 13
       slot: L2 CACHE
       size: 2MiB
       capacity: 2MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2

  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 25
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB

     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: M471B5173QH0-YK0
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 0
          serial: 209F7FFC
          slot: DIMM A
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)

     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: M471B5173QH0-YK0
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 1
          serial: 209F8134
          slot: DIMM B
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
```

Boot logs: https://pastebin.com/s7CtCSCF

Comment: Did you try an older kernel? Which kernel are you using? Provide more hardware info. Try a ubuntu live cd and run `uname -r`, `sudo lshw -c system -c memory`...

Comment: What method  exactly did you use to upgrade from 16.04 to 17.04?

Comment: kernel is 4.10.0-42-generic

Comment: Did you upgrade directly from 16.04 to 17.04 ? Or did you went through 16.10 ?

Comment: @N. Cornet yeah, directly upgraded

Comment: @Patel Can you post your boot messages? This command will give the boot messages from last boot: *journalctl -o short-precise -k*. Write it into a file: *journalctl -o short-precise -k > boot.txt* and then post it here. This way we can see more of what is happening.

Comment: @Patel Add it to your question. Put <code> tags around it, so it's easy to scroll through.

Comment: Attached file to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/s7CtCSCF

Comment: @G Trawo Attempted that but it told me it was above the char limit. Sorry for the limited expertise and hassle -- working with a laggy virtual keyboard is really frustrating hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to everyone that helped me! I fixed it! I hate when solutions go unposted so I hope this prevents anyone from wiping their hard drive like I did (luckily had backups - always have backups!)

The issue was that the computer needed a **bios update**. After some intense googling, I found a similar bug  relating to the tmp_crb error in a different kernel:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1394912

A random comment suggested updating bios. My bios version in the pastebin was listed as A08, the latest version for my motherboard was A12. I gave it a shot, after flashing the bios update the CPU hangups were fixed. Interestingly, the bios update description specifically said it fixed boot CPU hangups.

After updating, the computer performs dazzlingly. IT is immense pain, I hope to be rich enough one day to avoid fixing my mistakes.

Comment: Good show. Glad to hear you got it working. No shame in selecting this as the proper answer.